# How to extract name and number and make new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, strip

I have a column with a name and number, and I would like to extract the information and create 3 separate columns with the info in pandas using python. I'd like to also drop the original column. What is the most efficient code to do it? Is it feasible with a single line?

The number has brackets [] around it, which I also want to drop.

[image: Here is the example input with my desired output]

Thanks so much!

I'm a noob, don't have much experience with stripping/splicing and lambda functions within pandas.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str.extract` here with 3 capture groups for each component:

```py
df[["last", "first", "number"]] = df["last_first_number"].str.extract(r'(\w+), (\w+) \[(\d+)\]')
```